# Odd time gaps using POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

I may have discovered a curious gap in the passage of time in the early hours of 2017-10-01.  I have some well-worn code that I use often to create 30 minute intervals for summarising and plotting count observations.  The intervals start at around sunset and end around dawn - so the date changes at midnight.  For almost any pair of dates ('night') I care to input, my code works fine. But for the night of 2017-09-30, it skips two intervals 02:00 and 02:30.  Code below.

```
missing.times <- data.frame(isotime2=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-30 17:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 06:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by="30 min")); missing.times #missing 0200 and 0230

all.okay <- data.frame(isotime2=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 17:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2017-10-02 06:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by="30 min")); all.okay
```

I tried a sneaky workaround, but I still ultimately produce a gap.

```
#create intervals for the next date from midnight to 06:30
workaround <- data.frame(isotime2=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-10-02 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2017-10-02 06:30:00"), by="30 min")); workaround; str(workaround)

#substitute the following date for the time-gap date 2017-10-01
workaround$isotime2 <-gsub("2017-10-02", "2017-10-01", workaround$isotime2); workaround; str(workaround)

#change the vector "isotime2" from character to POSIXct magically makes time disappear
workaround$isotime2 <-as.POSIXct(workaround$isotime2, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); workaround; str(workaround)
```

Have I somehow created this time gap, or does R know something about a fold in space-time?  I was asleep when it happened.

Comment: I am guessing that you are in Australia.  The clocks changed for Daylight savings time on that date in Australia.

Comment: @G5W thanks, yes I am in Australia, and I did wonder about that, but I did not specify a time zone in the code, and we have some states that change for Daylight Saving, and others that don't.  Perhaps R knows I am in a state with Daylight Saving.  My data comes from a state that does not.  If I include `tz="Australia/Perth"` it does not fix it.

Comment: Look at your locale information from `sessionInfo()`. That can effect how times zones are interpreted. Where exactly did you put the `tz=` and what was the outcome you got vs what you expected?

Comment: If you don't specify a time zone, R will guess it for you. Try "Sys.time()" and note the tz that R assigns for you. This is the time zone that is being applied to your time data for you if you don't use it. tz = "Australia/Perth" will not fix it, because *in* that time zone, the times you've specified actually don't exist (because you "loose" an hour). If you want your graph to appear without a gap, you'll have to specify a time zone that does not change for daylight savings.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick (again!), @Nova.  You were right: `Sys.time()` gives me `2017-12-20 01:49:36 ACDT`, where ACDT is Australian Central Daylight Time (which does have Daylight saving).  Perth does not have Daylight Saving, so the time should exist there.

Comment: @MrFlick I used `tz` like this: `missing.times <- data.frame(isotime2=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-30 17:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 06:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Australia/Perth"), by="30 min")); missing.times #missing 0200 and 0230`

Comment: I don't think you can have two time zones in the same column.

Comment: `test <- as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 02:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Australia/Perth")` works, `test <- as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 02:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Australia/ACT")` doesn't work (test will be equal to `NA` in the second case).

Comment: Thanks @Nova. Perhaps a nice demonstration that `tz="Australia/Perth"` should work when put in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because @ptenax asked so nicely...

Use a time zone that doesn't change with daylight savings (let's face it, the bane of everyone's existence when coding).

First data.frame uses Australia/ACT tz which changes over at 2 AM, second data.frame uses Austalia/Perth tz which does not change for daylight savings.

```
missing.times <- data.frame(isotime2=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-30 17:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Australia/ACT"), as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 06:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Australia/ACT"), by="30 min"))
nrow(missing.times)
missing.times
# misses 2:00 and 2:30

missing.times <- data.frame(isotime2=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-30 17:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Australia/Perth"), as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 06:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Australia/Perth"), by="30 min"))
nrow(missing.times)
missing.times
# does not miss 2:00 and 2:30
```

Comment: Thank you kindly @Nova.  I only put the `tz` option in once instead of twice.  How silly.  Thanks for everyone's time.

Comment: I've struggled so much with time zones I feel like anything I can do to make it less painful for others... :P

Comment: Thanks - I saw that you also asked a question about Daylight Saving previously.